# Angular 5 remove class using wildcard

Tags: angular, angular5, renderer

I have an input attribute with a class :

```
<input class="color b1 b2 b3" text="text">
```

I want to remove all the classes after color so i can add other classes. But how to do it with a wildcard using .renderer.removeClass ?
So far i do this which is redundant and not clean

```
// remove class
this.renderer.removeClass(this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector(".color"), 'b1');
this.renderer.removeClass(this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector(".color"), 'b2');
this.renderer.removeClass(this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector(".color"), 'b3');
// add class
this.renderer.addClass(this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector(".color"), 'b4');
```

I tried something like this but with no success :

```
 this.renderer.removeClass(this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector(".color"), 'color*');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove all the `classes` of an element matching the `regex` as follows :

```
let el = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector(".color");
let regex = /^b\d$/;
let classes = el.getAttribute('class').split(' '); // get all classes
  classes.forEach((cl) => {
       if(cl.match(regex)) {  // match classes b1, b2, b3....
         this.renderer.removeClass(el, cl);
       }
  });
this.renderer.addClass(el, 'b4');
```

See this working [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/remove-class-renderer2?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Or more generic one : let regex = /[^color]/; Cause it's not always the same pattern b1, b2, etc